# I have forgotten the pattern for my samsung galaxy tab a i donot want to reset it please help

Tags: lock-screens

I have access to internet on the tab if that helps in any case. I have my study material there and I don't want to factory reset it what to do i hope to get help.

Comment: try to unlock from https://findmymobile.samsung.com